# jQuery click event syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The below code works well on `localhost` using XAMPP. But it doesn't work on another server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        word: <input type="text" id="sub" />
        user: <input type="text" id="user" />

        <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>

        <script>
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                var word=$("#sub").val();
                var usr=$("#user").val();
                alert("hi");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have got 2 errors from Chrome inspect element:

- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery-latest.js:5669`
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Do you have a copy of "jquery-latest.js" in the same folder of your html file?

Comment: Did you forget to deploy jquery-latest.js to the server?

Comment: sure..that file is there, I checked that first :) Some other problems i think

Comment: Try using the webkit inspector or Firefox's firebug tools to see if the jQuery javascript file is being loaded. One important thing to note is that Windows filesystems are case-insensitive, but most Linux file systems are case-sensitive, so check the `jquery-latest.js` file is the correct case.

Comment: You have some issues with your code too. Use `type="text/javascript"` in your `script` tags. Register the click event of the button in the ready event of the document. I think that not doing this will not mess with your code execution, but they are best practices.

Comment: Looks fine to me assuming, as the others have said, that your script file is in the right directory on your server. (You could test this by linking to an external copy of jQuery like from `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`)

Comment: i have got these 2 errors from chrome inspect element, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery-latest.js:5669
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @davidbuzatto `type="text/javascript"` is redundant, according to the latest HTML spec, but you're right about `$(document).ready()` that's most likely the issue. On his local machine it loads very fast, so that's why the click wire up works.

Comment: @Strelok and davidbuzatto: - use of document ready is unnecessary when the code is in a script block at the end of the body: the script will be executed after any elements before it are already parsed.

Comment: @Strelok: Thanks for the advice. I din't know that.

Comment: @nnnnnn obviously the error says otherwise (if jquery-latest.js is indeed deployed correctly).

Comment: @Strelok - the error is `$` is not defined, so if you tried to use `$(document).ready()` you'd _still_ get the error `$` is not defined.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've moved the script block with document.ready to the head tag in my answer. That is more correct.

Comment: your jquery-latest file is not uploaded correctly, try uploading it again.

Comment: Your Jquery file is clearly corrupted. Get latest from jQuery website and try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check jquery-latest.js is same directory with html file. Otherwise code is ok and also works.
add type in the script. try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery-latest.js:5669
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Also you can include jQuery from some jQuery CDN:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You need to wire up the click handler in the `$(document).ready()` event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btn").click(function () {
                var word=$("#sub").val();
                var usr=$("#user").val();
                alert("hi");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        word: <input type="text" id="sub" />
        user: <input type="text" id="user" />

        <button type="button" id="btn">Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No you don't. The browser basically parses the document top to bottom, and script blocks can access elements above them since those elements have already been parsed and added to the DOM. In the OP's code the script block is at the end of the body, so _all_ elements should be accessible from the code.

Comment: The scripts in **head** tag slows down the page rendering so it's better to place scripts at the end of body if possible.

Comment: @Jaison What was the solution?